# How to check if centroid of one rectangle is present inside another rectangle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, point, rectangles

I have a rectangle ABCD. I divide the rectangle into 9 equal parts by dividing the height and breadth by 3. Now I got 9 rectangles. If I consider one among these 9 rectangles ABCD_1 with coordinates = 166, 104, 332, 156. In addition to this I have another rectangle say PQRS whose centroid = 377.5, 489.0. I want to determine if the given centroid is present inside the rectangle ABCD_1. How to solve this.

I am a complete beginner in Python. Any help would be much appreciable. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your rectangle coordinates are represented as an array `[x1,y1,y2,x2]`
and point as `[x,y]`
then we will first check if x lies between the x coordinates of the rectangle and if yes then we'll check if they lie between y coordinates if true then the point lies inside the rectangle else doesn't.
below abcd is your rectangle and p is the point.

```
abcd=[166, 104, 332, 156]
p=[377.5, 489.0]

if p[0]>=abcd[0] and p[0]<=abcd[3]:
    if p[1]>=abcd[1] and p[0]<=abcd[2]:
        print('Inside')
else:
    print('Outside')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by the four numbers you have given I am guessing it is a rectangle with sides parallel to x and y axes. If your numbers are `(x1, y1), (x2, y2)` which are two opposite corners, and `P = (x, y)`, your logic should be

```
if x1 < x < x2 and y1 < y < y2:
    is_in_rect = True
```

where `x1 < x2` and `y1 < y2` (you need to adjust the comparison based on which numbers are larger)

For all `x1, y1, x2, y2 where x1!=x2, y1!=y2`,

```
if (x1 < x < x2 if x1 < x2 else x2 < x < x1) and \
   (y1 < y < y2 if y1 < y2 else y2 < y < y1):
    is_in_rect = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the code. But it doesn't solve my problem. Actually i have a Rectangle, I divide that into 9 equal parts. The coordinate of rectangle ABCD is given above which is one among the 9 segments. When I tried your logic, it gives the point is outside but actually it is inside. Just wondering what is wrong here.

Comment: 1. Is  your rectangle rotated? or sides parallel to `x` `y` axes?

Comment: Not rotated. Yes sides are parallel. The points are such that x,y,width,height

Comment: 2. Was I correct to assume the coordinates are two opposite corners, and the order is `x1, y1, x2, y2`?